# Too Many Redirects - WP-Admin Only

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, iis, shared-hosting

I have a couple of sites on a shared hosting server.

The sites load just fine, and everything appears to work, including local links. The only thing that isn't working is that the entire wp-admin directory is throwing a "too many redirects" error message.

Here is what my redirects look like to handle the domain (this is the only non-standard part of this install):

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="Site 2 Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog\.site2\.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/site2/" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I did see other posts claiming that the admin folder required 705 permissions, which I have set to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to enable WP_DEBUG 'ON' to find out the error. You  can enable WordPress debug editing wp-config.php  file by adding `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Check the following document for better understanding 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

I do not really know where your problem comes from but I know a trick to fix this issue in some case :

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

This code goes in main .htaccess at the very beginning.

Hope this will do the job.